# "Memory allocated with calloc must be freed all at once"?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, calloc

I read that memory allocated with `calloc` "must be freed all at once".

Does it mean that it's not the case with `malloc`?

If yes, could someone give me a real world example?
Many thanks!

Comment: I guess you could `realloc`, not sure whether any implementations do actually free the unused part of that memory though.

Comment: If you "read" something somewhere, you should provide a citation or quite in full for context.  In its own it is difficult to _guess_ what the author intended, the author may not have even been correct, or perhaps did not have English as a forest language.  Better surely to read and understand the documentation for the function itself; it will tell you everything anyone can know about the function itself.

Comment: @Clifford: Sorry, I lost the source :/...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory allocated with `calloc` and `malloc` is freed the same way: by passing the pointer returned by the allocator to `free`.

The confusion might come from the fact that `calloc` is called with 2 arguments to allocate an array, one argument for the element size and the other for the number of elements. *All at once* might refer to the fact that the elements cannot not be freed individually, `free` must be called with a pointer to the initial element, which is the pointer returned by `calloc`.

A call to `calloc(n1, n2)` is semantically equivalent to this:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *calloc(size_t n1, size_t n2) {
    if (n1 != 0 && n2 > SIZE_MAX / n1)
        return NULL;
    size_t size = n1 * n2;
    void *p - malloc(size);
    if (p != NULL)
        memset(p, 0, size);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: You definitely got the point. This sentence was probably put in the source (that I lost...) to get people away from the idea of freeing the allocated elements individually... But it totally confused me! Thanks for the equivalent code!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing semantically different about `calloc()` except that it initialises the allocated memory to all bits 0 (while `malloc()` does not).

> The calloc() function shall allocate unused space for an array of
> nelem elements each of whose size in bytes is elsize.  The space
> shall be initialized to all bits 0.

The pointer passed to `free()` must point to the same memory block as was returned by a call to the memory allocation functions, otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

> The free() function shall cause the space pointed to by ptr to be
> deallocated; that is, made available for further allocation. If
> ptr is a null pointer, no action shall occur. Otherwise, if the
> argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a function
> in POSIX.1‐2008 that allocates memory as if by malloc(), or if
> the space has been deallocated by a call to free() or realloc(),
> the behavior is undefined.

If the intent is to `free()` unused space (shrinking the allocated memory block), consider resizing it with `realloc()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It confirms my understanding of the usage of thoses functions. Actually, as chqrlie said, my confusion came from the fact that the author of the quote (that I lost) was trying to avoid confusion... But confused me!